# Program for setting global hotkeys on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hotkeys

On WinXP, I used to use [qliner hotkeys](http://www.qliner.com/hotkeys/) for starting programs with global hotkeys (for example Win+I for web browser). But qliner hotkeys crashes on Win7 x64, so I need to find another program for setting global hotkeys. Which program do you recommend?

Comment: Related: [Is a there a shortcut key to go to a specific window (on Windows 7)?](https://superuser.com/q/518083/354511)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com). Nothing else.

Simple, yet very powerful, syntax, good scripting, lightweight, so on. It's almost perfect, and can do just about anything you ask of it.

Slight niggle with win7: It must be run as administrator to have hotkeys functioning in elevated apps.

Comment: Autohotkey's user interface isn't too good (it requires writing scripts), but I suppose I'll use it for now. If I ever need more scripting, then its other features might be useful, although then I might as well write a program in a more serious programming language.

Comment: It's a very powerful scripting language, though. If you're doing hardcore maths, then yes, go for something more suited, but as a language it's really very powerful. Moving windows, pressing keys, sending messages to windows, so on.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 7, it's possible to start programs which have been pinned to taskbar by pressing `Win+1`, `Win+2` etc. hotkeys. So Windows 7 has built-in hotkeys for starting up to 10 programs.

If the program is already open, then `Win+<number>` changes the active window or minimizes the only open window. `Win+Shift+<number>`, `Win+Alt+<number>` and `Win+Ctrl+<number>` also do some things.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221232418/http://teaching.droidsdk.com/?p=66) simple methond without installing any software and using only shortcuts and cmd /k

hope it's useful!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: Supported only Ctrl+Alt+? (AltGr+?).

Answer (score 0):

[Hot Key Plus](http://www.brianapps.net/hotkeyplus/) of 2001 is working on Windows 8.
Or [MKey](http://web.archive.org/web/20190415102646/http://www.seriosoft.org/en/index.php)